# Receiving a compile error after updating to Angular 9

Tags: angular

I am receiving the following error when I try to build my project after updating to Angular version 9 from 8.2 [image]

I followed every step in the update Angular guide.

Comment: This could be a problem witth AOT compilation. Angular 9 uses Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation by default. When you were on v8.2, could you run your project locally with `ng serve --aot`? If you deployed your project after building with the `--prod` flag and it worked fine, this is likely not the issue. If you didn't deploy with the `--prod` flag, this is worth looking into.

Comment: I have never used `--aot` before, to be honest. I do however only deploy after  successful compilation with the `--prod` flag. And I haven't had any issues before

Comment: Gotcha. When you build with the `--prod` flag, it automatically uses the AOT compiler. Because your app successfully ran after deploying that way, the AOT compiler probably isn't the cause of your issue.

Comment: v9 updated Typescript from 3.6 to 3.7 so maybe it's something to do with the way your Typescript is compiling. Maybe check to see if you're using any TS features impacted by these breaking changes => https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#breaking-Changes

Comment: @KylerJohnson, thank you for your help! Your last comment gave me guidance as to what to look out for, and luckily it didn't take me 24 years to find it. I found that in a template I iterate over an observable using the `| async as` pipe syntax, but I named the `as variable` the same as the `control variable`. That was the "already defined" issue. Thanks again

Comment: Ah, good find! Glad I could somewhat help